# Does graphics32 works in c++ builder XE2?

Tags: c++builder, c++builder-xe2, graphics32

I have installed graphics32 1.9.1 1581, compiled and added the GR32_DSGN_RSXE2 package.
But it has no .h files and your components and components folders are visible only in Delphi projects. Its implementation for C++ has stoped in builder 6? There is a way to use it in cbuilder XE2? There is a substitute for?

Comment: Better use common [tag:c++builder] tag along with the specific version [tag:c++builder-xe2] tag to pay more attention ;-)

Comment: GR32 works up to XE4 (that I've tested) so you should be fine. Chances are the BPL projects are not set to emit C++ files. Open the project properties for each one, and in the linker output set it to emit all C++ files (.lib, .hpp, etc.)

Answer (score 1):

If you only get the packages and not the full source, then you are out of luck. If on the other hand, they provide the source, you can usually just rebuild them with the right settings to generate the files needed for c++.